# creating a udp client but its not returning any response,should I need to create a server if I am using localhost

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, python-sockets

I have created a udp client

```
    import socket
    target_host = "127.0.0.1"
    target_port = 80  
    # create a socket object
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    # send some data
    client.sendto("AAABBBCCC",(target_host,target_port))
    # receive some data
    data, addr = client.recvfrom(4096)
    print data
```

after I created the server

```
     from socket import  *
     server=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)

     server.bind(("127.0.0.1",80))
     print("server running")
     server.recvfrom(80)
```

there might be mistakes in my code please help me to correct it,and I also dont know if a server is needed or not

Comment: Looks like your server never sends any packets, so that could explain why your client never receives any response.